# Program functions when "elif" is used, but does not when "elif" is replaced with "if". I am having trouble figuring out why? (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a small rock paper scissors program in python. The following code is functional. When I replace the "elif" with "if" the program is not completely functional (returns the else statement often) and I do not understand why. I am aware that elif should be used, but I still do not understand why using "if" is causing a loss in functionality. Thanks!

```
import random
game = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")
userchoice = str(input("rock, paper, or scissors?"))
while (userchoice == "rock" or "paper" or "scissors"):
    computerchoice = random.choice(game)
    if (computerchoice == "rock" and userchoice == "scissors"):
        print("you lose",computerchoice,"beats",userchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    elif (computerchoice == "scissors" and userchoice == "paper"):
        print("you lose",computerchoice,"beats",userchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    elif (computerchoice == "paper" and userchoice == "rock"):
        print("you lose",computerchoice,"beats",userchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    elif (computerchoice == "rock" and userchoice == "paper"):
        print("you win",userchoice,"beats",computerchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    elif (computerchoice == "scissors" and userchoice == "rock"):
        print("you win",userchoice,"beats",computerchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    elif (computerchoice == "paper" and userchoice == "scissors"):
        print("you win",userchoice,"beats",computerchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    elif (computerchoice == userchoice):
        print("tie")
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    else:
        print("what?")
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
```

Comment: Your `while` loop condition is suspect.  It should be `userchoice in game`.  The way you have it now, you're checking if `"paper"` itself is truthy which it always is.

Comment: What input do you type in to reach the `else` block?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the elif to if the program won't work correctly 
For example,
    take 1st case if computerchoice is rock userchoice is scissors then it asks for      input again. But now the execution continues from the next if statement ie

```
if (computerchoice == "scissors" and userchoice == "paper"):
```

So if you the same case comes again ie computerchoice is rock userchoice is scissors it wont check the first condition and execute else block.

For further explanation comment

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation to this is that if there are **MULTIPLE** `if` statements in a loop then **ONLY** the first occurrence of `if`/`else` statement is executed and the loop completes and continues the next loop without checking other `if` statements. Your program works correctly in case of `elif` statement is because, after the `if` statement program continues checking all other `elif` statements

Answer (score 0):

To use if..else statement, you must change the code in this way:

```
import random
game = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")
userchoice = str(input("rock, paper, or scissors?"))
while (userchoice in game):
    computerchoice = random.choice(game)
    if (computerchoice == "rock" and userchoice == "scissors"):
        print("you lose",computerchoice,"beats",userchoice)
        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
    else:
        if (computerchoice == "scissors" and userchoice == "paper"):
            print("you lose",computerchoice,"beats",userchoice)
            userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
        else:
            if (computerchoice == "paper" and userchoice == "rock"):
                print("you lose",computerchoice,"beats",userchoice)
                userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
            else:
                if (computerchoice == "rock" and userchoice == "paper"):
                    print("you win",userchoice,"beats",computerchoice)
                    userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
                else:
                    if (computerchoice == "scissors" and userchoice == "rock"):
                        print("you win",userchoice,"beats",computerchoice)
                        userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
                    else:
                        if (computerchoice == "paper" and userchoice == "scissors"):
                            print("you win",userchoice,"beats",computerchoice)
                            userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
                        else:
                            if (computerchoice == userchoice):
                                print("tie")
                                userchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
                            else:
                                print("what?")
                                rockuserchoice = str(input("try again, rock, paper, or scissors?"))
```